# Как реализовать загруску выбранного мной языка в другой карте в Unity?

Tags: unity3d

Суть в том, был сделан скрипт по переключению локализации в игре на android, и выбирая в меню язык, при переходе на другую карту он сбрасываеться.
Я знаю что через PlayerPrefs, но не доконца как это в скрипте реализовать.
И из-за чего может быть эта ошибка?
IndexOutOfRangeException: Array index is out of range.
DilScripti.Update () (at Assets/Game/Lang/DilScripti.cs:24)
Вот скрипт!

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class DilScripti : MonoBehaviour {

public Text[] dildegiskenleri;

public string[] en,ru,fr;
public int dildegeri;

public Sprite[] sp;

public Button dilbt;  ///


private void Update()
{
    dilbt.image.sprite = sp[dildegeri];
if (dildegeri == 1){                 
    dildegiskenleri[0].text = en[0];
    dildegiskenleri[1].text = en[1];  //Сюда вставляем слова в unity editor
    dildegiskenleri[2].text = en[2];  
    dildegiskenleri[3].text = en[3];
    dildegiskenleri[4].text = en[4];
}
if (dildegeri == 2){

    dildegiskenleri[0].text = ru[0];
    dildegiskenleri[1].text = ru[1];
    dildegiskenleri[2].text = ru[2];
    dildegiskenleri[3].text = ru[3];
    dildegiskenleri[4].text = ru[4];
}
if (dildegeri == 3){      
    dildegiskenleri[0].text = fr[0];  
    dildegiskenleri[1].text = fr[1];
    dildegiskenleri[2].text = fr[2];
    dildegiskenleri[3].text = fr[3];
    dildegiskenleri[4].text = fr[4];
}
}


private void Start()
{
    dildegeri = 1;
}

private void Awake()
{
    dildegeri = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("dilst",dildegeri);
}


private void LateUpdate()
{
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("dilst", dildegeri);
    PlayerPrefs.Save();
}


public void dildegistir(){
    if (dildegeri <=2)
    {
        dildegeri +=1;
    }
    else {
        dildegeri = 1;
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Вообще я бы не советовал городить свою систему локализации а воспользоватся чужой. Благо, песплатных систем локализации среди ассетов просто море.

Немного посмотрев на код:
Да и с названиями у классов да переменных нужно было бы поработать... ужас какой-то.

Да и присваивать на каждом кадре весь аррей это просто какой-то трэш...

Мой личный совет: Серьезно... Забей на свои наработки и разберись с одним из ассетов из соответствующей категориии ассетов: https://assetstore.unity.com/categories/tools/localization

Да, я знаю что это не ответ. Но это лучшее что можно в даном случае посоветовать.

Comment: Все равно спасибо!